# add rows in a data.table but not when certain columns take same values

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, reshape, reshape2

I have a data.table `dat` with 4 columns, say (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`).

Input data:

```
structure(list(col1 = c(5.1, 5.1, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 4.7, 
4.6, 5), col2 = c(3.5, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.5, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 
3.6), col3 = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 3.4, 3.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4
), col4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica", "eer"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

r
    col1 col2 col3   col4
 1:  5.1  3.5  1.4 setosa
 2:  5.1  3.5  1.4 setosa
 3:  4.7  3.2  1.3 setosa
 4:  4.6  3.1  1.5 setosa
 5:  5.0  3.6  1.4 setosa
 6:  5.1  3.5  3.4    eer
 7:  5.1  3.5  3.4    eer
 8:  4.7  3.2  1.3    eer
 9:  4.6  3.1  1.5    eer
10:  5.0  3.6  1.4    eer
```

I am performing a following operation on `col3` for each unique value of `col4`

```
dat[ , r_new:= sum(col3, na.rm = T), .(col4)]    #syntax 1
```

So, above sytnax is creating a new column `r_new` with values got by adding those values of `col3` where `col4` is same. So, each unique value of `col4` will have a unuique value in column `r_new`.

**What I want to do now, is do the same as above but *not* include those rows where `col1` and `col2` are taking same values (something like below)**

```
dat[col1 is different OR col2 is different , r_new:= sum(col3, na.rm = T), .(col4)]
```

What this will do, while performing `sum` function over rows, it will not include those rows where both `col1` and `col2` are taking same values.

How can I include this condition in the same syntax as 1?

Expected Output:

```
    col1 col2 col3   col4 r_new
 1:  5.1  3.5  1.4 setosa   5.6
 2:  5.1  3.5  1.4 setosa   5.6
 3:  4.7  3.2  1.3 setosa   5.6
 4:  4.6  3.1  1.5 setosa   5.6
 5:  5.0  3.6  1.4 setosa   5.6
 6:  5.1  3.5  3.4    eer   7.6
 7:  5.1  3.5  3.4    eer   7.6
 8:  4.7  3.2  1.3    eer   7.6
 9:  4.6  3.1  1.5    eer   7.6
10:  5.0  3.6  1.4    eer   7.6
```

As you can see in the expected output, for `setosa` row 1 and 2 took same value for `col1` and `col2` and for `err` rows 6 and 7 took same values for `col1` and `col2`, so we did not add those rows (we just considered them once). Dont worry about `col3` (it will take same value if `col1` and `col2` are taking same values.

**EDIT: Second dput:**

```
structure(list(col1 = c(5.1, 5.1, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 4.7, 
4.6, 5.1), col2 = c(3.5, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.5, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 
3.4), col3 = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 3.4, 3.4, 1.3, 1.5, 3.4
), col4 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), r_new = c(5.6, 5.6, 
    5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6, 9.6)), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4", "count", "r_new"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

    col1 col2 col3 col4 count r_new
 1:  5.1  3.5  1.4    A     1   5.6
 2:  5.1  3.5  1.4    A     1   5.6
 3:  4.7  3.2  1.3    A     1   5.6
 4:  4.6  3.1  1.5    A     1   5.6
 5:  5.0  3.6  1.4    A     1   5.6
 6:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   9.6
 7:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   9.6
 8:  4.7  3.2  1.3    B     1   9.6
 9:  4.6  3.1  1.5    B     1   9.6
10:  5.1  3.4  3.4    B     1   9.6
```

**EDIT 2: Third dput**

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 count r_new
 1:  5.1  3.5  1.4    A     1   5.6
 2:  5.1  3.5  1.4    A     1   5.6
 3:  4.7  3.2  1.3    A     1   5.6
 4:  4.6  3.1  1.5    A     1   5.6
 5:  5.0  3.6  1.4    A     1   5.6
 6:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   6.2
 7:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   6.2
 8:  4.7  3.2  1.3    B     1   6.2
 9:  4.6  3.1  1.5    B     1   6.2
10:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   6.2


structure(list(col1 = c(5.1, 5.1, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 4.7, 
4.6, 5.1), col2 = c(3.5, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.5, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 
3.5), col3 = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 3.4, 3.4, 1.3, 1.5, 3.4
), col4 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), r_new = c(5.6, 5.6, 
    5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 6.2, 6.2, 6.2, 6.2, 6.2)), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4", "count", "r_new"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: can't you filter beforehand?

Comment: Can you show `dat` and expected output please

Comment: @mtoto I have added example.

Comment: @MattDowle yes, it should be 6.2 only. 9.6 answer is given by mtoto's answer. To show him, I copied the result as is. Let me edit it and write the correct answer.

Comment: No. there `col2` is different for row 10. So, row 6 and row 10 are 2 different combinations of col1 and col2. only those rows need to be considered where both col1 and col2 are same at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

We can subset `col3` inside `j` using `?data.table::duplicated`.

```
dat[, r_new := sum(col3[!duplicated(.SD, by = c("col1","col2"))], na.rm = T), by = col4]  

> dat
#      col1 col2 col3 col4 count r_new
# 1:  5.1  3.5  1.4    A     1   5.6
# 2:  5.1  3.5  1.4    A     1   5.6
# 3:  4.7  3.2  1.3    A     1   5.6
# 4:  4.6  3.1  1.5    A     1   5.6
# 5:  5.0  3.6  1.4    A     1   5.6
# 6:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   6.2
# 7:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   6.2
# 8:  4.7  3.2  1.3    B     1   6.2
# 9:  4.6  3.1  1.5    B     1   6.2
#10:  5.1  3.5  3.4    B     1   6.2
```

Comment: Thanks. I had another doubt but I have posted it as another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233318/count-unique-by-2-columns-in-a-data-table 

Can you please answer that also?

Comment: Yes. I was experimenting and I found an issue. Please look at the second dput and your solution is not working. Please let me know, why?

Comment: In the second example, for value `B` the answer should be 9.6 and not 6.2. Why is it happening?

Comment: Well, not the reverse is happening. Please apply your updated solution on the new dput (Added in the question). This time answer should be 6.2

Comment: Will look at it later, on my phone now.

Comment: The `duplicated()` just needed to be on `.SD` rather than the whole `df`, iiuc. I tested with the minor fix so made the edit - hope ok.

Comment: @user3664020 Don't forget to accept this one please.  I deleted my other answer from before I realized there was a simple fix for this one.

Comment: @MattDowle curious what your solution was. Big fan of `data.table`, you guys are doing an awesome job!

Comment: @mtoto Sure - undeleted.  Much thanks for encouragement.

Answer (score 2):

Accept mtoto's answer as that's easier to read, but here's an alternative.

```
DT[, r_new:=unique(.SD,by=c("col1","col2"))[,sum(col3, na.rm=TRUE)], by=col4]
```